# Redirect loop when activating CloudFlare

Tags: node.js, redirect, ssl, cloudflare

I am trying to put my [website](https://ligatures.net) behind [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) but unfortunately when I activate CloudFlare I start getting a redirect loop (I am using Chrome).

I have tried to clear the cookies, as recommended, but it does not solve the issue and I am not having this issue when CloudFlare is not activated.

What is causing this and how to solve it in my `node.js` application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently, this was a configuration issue. I was on Flexible SSL and changed it to full SSL.

My `node.js` app was receiving HTTP requests from CloudFlare and redirected to HTTPS, which CloudFlare converted back to HTTP, etc...

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar issue. I had previously had a 301 redirect to https enabled and Cloudflare's servers read that and did not work with the Flexible SSL setting. I'm waiting for the 301 to expire from their cache before enabling flexible again. Switching to strict seems to fix the issue until my certificate expires. At which point I'll attempt to use flexible again.

Comment: I needed to do this with my wordpress site configured using trellis and letsencrypt. enabling full (strict) (because the certificate is handled by letsencrypt) on the Crypto page stopped the loop

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WordPress by chance? We do have directions on the [redirect loop after enabling SSL](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203487280--How-do-I-fix-the-infinite-redirect-loop-error-after-enabling-Flexible-SSL-with-WordPress-).

Comment: The accepted answer worked for me with a wordpress install configured using trellis and letsencrypt: enabling full (strict) (because the certificate is handled by letsencrypt) on the cloudflare Crypto page stopped the loop

Answer (score -1):

just change your SSL mode to strict.

Comment: It is better if you can explain your answer and try as possible to give a detailed answer.